# Tem como exportar um arquivo JAR apenas com classes Kotlin, sem nenhuma classe de Java?

Tags: kotlin, intellij

Estou usando `Intellij IDEA` para desenvolver um projeto em Kotlin, e cheguei a um ponto que preciso criar um arquivo executável para rodar no servidor, mas quando tento criar um `JAR Artifact`, não consigo pois preciso informar uma Main Class em Java, coisa que não há no projeto. Vocês tem alguma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir uma classe com o método `main` que seja reconhecido pelo Intellij de duas formas:

```
object MainClass {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("Sou uma classe com um main definido")
    }
}
```

Ou:

```
class MainClass 

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Sou uma classe com um main definido")
}
```

Ambos os casos são listados como possíveis classes principais para seu jar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]